# How to access specific values in a multilevel pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a pandas dataframe, my_table with multilevel columns like so:

```
       SITE_NO             DATETIME     VALUE
index                                      A        B      C       D
0          123  2011-11-16 12:00:00        1        3      5       7
1          456  2011-11-28 12:00:00        2        4      6       8
```

where 'VALUE' has subcolumns 'A' 'B' 'C' and 'D'. I know I can use

```
my_table ['VALUE']
```

to get this:

```
index    A       B    C      D
0        1       3    5      7
1        2       4    6      8
```

I'm wondering, how can I reference specific values such as the 1 under column A at index 0?

Comment: @roganjosh I had tried to look for some more info in the docs and on SO but somehow I missed the multiindexing page. (admittedly I'm not much of a fan of the layout of the pandas docs) So, just to be certain, I would use my_table.loc [0, ('VALUE', 'A')] to get 1? Sorry about the crappy question, and thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [tuple to access multiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index):

```
df.loc[0, ('Value','A')]
```

Output:

```
1
```